# Can Scenario Outline auto generate data from filesystem?

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, specflow

I am trying to run a set of steps for testing the processing of files in a given folder. I would like to be able to see each processed files result rather than one executing to the first failure.

Instead of having a step to populate a List for each test file in a directory and then have steps to loop through this list in order to process each file then compare output to expected results, I am hoping it is possible to use Scenario Outline to make it so I can be more specific in my tests.

For example, instead of this:

```
# Feature Details ...
Scenario:
Given I have some data
When I process the data
Then I expect the output to be consistent
```

I would like something like:

```
#Feature Details:
Scenario Outline:
Given I have a file <file>
When I process the data
Then I expect the output to be consistent
Example:
    | file |
    | [dynamically populate this list of files given a directory path] |
```

Is this even possible?

Can I specify something like:

```
Example:
    <file> in [DirectoryInfo(path)].Files
```

Or:

```
Example:
    | file |
    | ScenarioContext.Current[FilesToTest] |
```

However I doubt this is possible, but I am rather new to C# and spec flow so wanted to ask here just in case.

Comment: You want a seperate test for every file you have in the examples table? Then ScenarioOutline is the correct one. See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem? just replace ?? with a directory relative to test runnning folder and everything should work ok. you might have to create the folder with the data in, and to do that my suggestion would be to include the data you want to use in the test as resource files in the test project and have your given step create the necessary folder and populate it with the data from the resources files

**EDIT**

you can't dynamically generate a list of files in the example, but your step can read a collection of files from a path easily enough.

If the files already exist in your test environment then you have a few options I believe.

If your files are always in the same known location, then just put this location in the example, then in the step you can iterate those files. I'd change the feature to something like this:

```
#Feature Details:
Scenario Outline:
Given I have a many files in the folder <InputFolder>
When I process each of the files
Then I expect the output for each processsed file to the same as the results in <OutputFolder>
Example:
    | InputFolder    | OutpuFolder    |
    | c:\inputFiles\ | c:\outputFiles |
```

[Given("I have a many files in the folder (.*)")]
public void GivenIHaveManyFiles(string exampleLocation)
{
    List filesToProcess = new List();
    foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(exampleLocation))
    {
        filesToProcess.Add(file.FullName);
    }
    ScenarioContext.Current["FilesToProcess"] = filesToProcess;
}

if (more likely) the files are in different locations in each environment or on your local machine then I would probably use an environment variable or some config. With an environment variable:

```
var location = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(exampleName);
foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(location))
{
    //use the file
}
```

this will require you to set up the environment variable on each server but its likely the the CI can do this as part of the build setup (we do this in TeamCity).

You could also have your CI create a text file with the file locations in before the test run starts and then read this text file to get the location in your tests.  there are many ways to skin this cat.

This is not really a specflow issue, just imagine you were writing a console application to read these values, how would you do it then?

Comment: I was not sure if I could do that. In my CI environment I have several stages that test different configurations. The initial and expected test data already exist in each environment. All the examples I have seen specified the table of test data. I was just wondering if I could provide a folder path that would generate the list for me? If so how would that need to be specified in the feature file? This is because each CI environment has different files so I can't name them in the list. This test data is not controlled by me.

Comment: @izzycoding please see my edit, hopefully this will help you towards a solution.

Comment: this is pretty much what I have at present, but this will stop at the first failed comparison. I was hoping to be able to test each file individually, but without having to name each file explicitly. I suppose it is just not possible.